# High CPU Utilization on EC2 of a Spring MVC micro service with authentication disabled

Tags: spring, amazon-ec2, cors, cpu, thread-dump

One of the services is giving **high CPU utilization**.
I analysed the thread dump and found the following stacktrace to be the culprit of the problem. But I am not able to identify how to fix it.
This is one of the instances of the service where the **auth security is disbaled**. There are two more instances which are running with auth enabled and they are running fine.
How can I solve this issue?

```
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3812)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4799)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4731)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3812)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4286)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4248)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.matchInit(Pattern.java:4818)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Prolog.match(Pattern.java:4755)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.match(Matcher.java:1270)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.matches(Matcher.java:604)
at com.hidden.filter.CorsProvider.isValidOriginHost(CorsProvider.java:89)
at com.hidden.filter.CorsProvider.checkAndUpdateAllowedReferer(CorsProvider.java:65)
at com.hidden.filter.CorsProvider.updateCorsHeaders(CorsProvider.java:43)
at com.hidden.filter.CorsProvider.updateCorsHeaders(CorsProvider.java:28)
at com.hidden.exp.properties.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:70)
```

Comment: Can you show the regular expression(s) you're using? One (or more) of them likely is vulnerable to catastrophic backtracking.